# For loops to Stream

Tags: java, loops, java-8, java-stream

I'm learning about Streams and ParallelStreams and now I trying apply this. I'm changing my codes which contains *for* loops to *streams* but I can't change some part of my code. First, it's possible reduce this code to Streams?

With foreach loops

```
private List<BasicDBObject> linhaCriativa(List<BasicDBObject> linhas) {
        List<BasicDBObject> lista = new ArrayList<>();
        for (BasicDBObject db : linhas) {
            if (!db.toMap().containsKey("spec_linha-criativa")) {
                lista.add(db);
                continue;
            }
            String[] linhaCriativa = db.get("spec_linha-criativa").toString().split(";");
            if (linhaCriativa.length > 0) {
                for (String criativa : linhaCriativa) {
                    BasicDBObject dbObject = (BasicDBObject) db.copy();
                    dbObject.replace("spec_linha-criativa", criativa);
                    lista.add(dbObject);
                }
            } else {
                lista.add(db);
            }
        }
        return lista;
    }
```

I can do this, but I can't do when db.toMap().**containsKey**("spec_linha-criativa")

```
List<BasicDBObject> notContains = linhas.parallelStream().filter(m -> !m.toMap().containsKey("spec_linha-criativa")).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your code correctly, for each BasicDBObject in the input list, you extract one or several BasicDBObjects, and add them to the output list.

This is a `flatMap()` operation:

```
return linhas.stream()
             .flatMap(this::extractOutputDbObjectsFrom)
             .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Now you need to create the `extractOutputDbObjectsFrom` method:

```
private Stream<BasicDBObject> extractOutputDbObjectsFrom(DbObject db) {
    if (!db.toMap().containsKey("spec_linha-criativa")) {
        return Stream.of(db);
    }

    String[] linhaCriativa = db.get("spec_linha-criativa").toString().split(";");
    if (linhaCriativa.length > 0) {
        return Arrays.stream(linhaCriativa).map(criativa -> {
            BasicDBObject dbObject = (BasicDBObject) db.copy();
            dbObject.replace("spec_linha-criativa", criativa);
            return dbObject;
        });
    } else {
        return Stream.of(db);
    }
}
```

(not tested, but you should get the idea)